# Does composer need to installed in order to perform a rollback?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is it necessary  to have the composer installed in order to execute

`migrate:rollback` in laravel 4?

I get this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'AddUsernameToUsersTable' not found","file":"\/home\/ecoadven\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Migrations\/Migrator.php","line":301}}
```

Comment: 1) Composer is a PHP script, no need to install that. 2) You don't need composer at all to run a PHP script (what you're doing here). It is just handy because it does a lot for you. 3) Composer creates an autoloader for you, i guess that you don't have an autoloader here, so it cannot find the class you need.

Comment: @Blaatpraat thanks! I didn't realize that composer was just a script, I downloaded the script , run `php composer.phar dumpautoload ` and everything is fine...

Answer (score 0):

without composer all the files from the laravel framework are not loaded, you need to [require](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and [import](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) these manualy in every file where you need them.

I would recommend you to use composer, this makes it a lot easier. Or do you have a particular reason why you don't want to use it?